# Modelica.Math.Vectors.Utilities.roots returns correct absolute values of roots but wrong sign

Tags: modelica

I am trying to compute the roots of a 3rd order polynomial utilizing the `Modelica.Math.Vectors.Utilities.roots` function.

The polynomial 0 = -pi/3*h^3+pi*r*h^2-V translates into the coefficient vector `p={-Modelica.Constants.pi/3,Modelica.Constants.pi*r,0,-V}` with `r=0.5` and `V=0.251327`.

Wolfram alpha returns the following three roots: -0.35928; 0.486663; 1.37262

When computing the roots in Modelica with the given function, I get the following result: -1.37262; -0.486663; 0.35928

So the absolute values of the results are equal but the signs in Modelica are not correct.

Maybe I am missing something, but I can't figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

That seems like an issue with a specific outdated version of MSL (Modelica Standard Library) or possibly some unspecified tool.

In Dymola 2018 FD01 I get the same roots as in Wolfram; using MSL 3.2.2 (but in reverse order).
In Dymola 2022 the function is called Modelica.Math.Polynomials.roots (due to MSL 4.0.0) but also give the same result.

I would report it to the tool; or update.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I updated to MSL 4.0.0 and started using the Polynomials.roots function (since the Vector.roots function does not seem to exist in MSL 4.0.0 anymore) but still get the same weird result. So maybe this is an openmodelica problem instead of an MSL problem.

Comment: In OpenModelica (master branch) on Linux, I get the same results and order as Hans... `{{1.372616888426636,0.0},{0.4866629786091502,0.0},{-0.3592798670357852,0.0}}`

Comment: So far, I tried it on windows with openmodelica MSL 3.2.3 and MSL 4.0.0. I also tried it on Linux using MSL 3.2.3. No matter where I try it, I still get the same flipped signs. This is the basic model that gives me the wrong results: `model Test   import Modelica.Units.SI.{Radius,Volume};   import Modelica.Constants;   Real r[3, 2];   parameter Real p[4] = {-Modelica.Constants.pi / 3, Modelica.Constants.pi * ri, 0, -v};   parameter Volume v = 0.251327;   parameter Radius ri = 0.5; equation   r = Modelica.Math.Polynomials.roots(p); end Test;`